# Is it possible to change the windowed mode resolution?

Tags: neocron

In Neocron it is possible through the launcher to set your graphics mode to "Windowed Mode", but it does not appear to be possible to change the resolution:

[image: Change resolution]

Is it possible to set a custom windowed mode resolution? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set a custom windowed mode resolution through the Neocron launcher, however, if you completely exit the game and edit the neocron.ini file within your Neocron installation folder, it is possible to set one manually.

Simply open the neocron.ini file and edit the following line;

> ```
> PREFWINDOWSIZE = "1440x900x32"
> ```

Change the value of "1440x900x32" to watch the Width x Height x Colour Depth that you wish, for example "1920x1080x32" will set a resolution of 1920x1080 with a colour depth of 32bit.

It is not possible to run Neocron in a 'borderless' window mode, so whatever resolution you set here will be in addition to a window border.

Comment: If you want it in windowed borderless mode, you might check [this](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2675769) out. I recently started using it, and it works great!